# Check a value with another value in different table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I using flask and flask-sqlalchemy.

I have two model like below:

```
class Reserve(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_reserves'
    reserve_id = db.Column(db.String(12), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.String(36), db.ForeignKey('tbl_users.user_id'))
    saloon_id = db.Column(db.String(36), db.ForeignKey('tbl_saloons.saloon_id'))
    hour = db.Column(db.String(3))
    date = db.Column(db.String(50))
    status = db.Column(db.String(10))
    reserve_datetime = db.Column(db.String(120))
```

```
class Payments(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_payments'
    payment_id = db.Column(db.String(10), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.String(11), db.ForeignKey('tbl_users.user_id'))
    reserve_id = db.Column(db.String(12), db.ForeignKey('tbl_reserves.reserve_id'))
    refid = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    authorize = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=True)
    date_time = db.Column(db.String(50))
    status = db.Column(db.String(10))
```

and i want **Insert** a new **Payments** instance when **reserve_id** exists in **Reserve** model and **status** of **Payments** model is not success.

I used to this query:

```
Payments.query.join(Reserve).filter(Reserve.reserve_id == reserve_id, Payments.status != 'success').first()
```

But it's not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to know that a successful payment doesn't exist:

```
reserve_id = 1   # or wherever you're getting it from

has_successful_payment = bool(session.query(func.count(Payments.payment_id).filter(Payments.reserve_id == reserve_id, Payments.status == 'success').scalar())

if has_successful_payment:
    # don't allow a new payment
    pass
else:
    # code to insert a new payment
    pass
```